# How can retrieve navigational data in model using entity framework database first

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have created a database from sql server and used the entity framework power tools which generated the models and dbcontext for me.

It has two classes:

```
Lookup_System: which is 1st table
Lookup_SubSystem: which is 2nd table with has relationship like: SystemID from  Lookup_SubSystem points to SystemID from Lookup_System base table.
```

I can only get the data from Lookup_SubSystem table where as navigational fields are always null or empty.

Am i doing something wrong?

```
public partial class Lookup_System
{
    public Lookup_System()
    {
        this.Lookup_SubSystem = new List<Lookup_SubSystem>();
    }
    public long SystemID { get; set; }
    public string SystemDesc { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> SOrder { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Lookup_SubSystem> Lookup_SubSystem { get; set; }
}

public partial class Lookup_SubSystem
{
    public Lookup_SubSystem()
    {
        this.Lookup_ComponentType = new List<Lookup_ComponentType>();
    }

    public long SubSystemID { get; set; }
    public string SubSystemDesc { get; set; }
    public long SystemID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> SOrder { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Lookup_ComponentType> Lookup_ComponentType { get; set; }

    public virtual Lookup_System Lookup_System { get; set; }
}

public class Lookup_SubSystemMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Lookup_SubSystem>
{
    public Lookup_SubSystemMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.SubSystemID);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.SubSystemDesc)
            .HasMaxLength(250);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Lookup_SubSystem");
        this.Property(t => t.SubSystemID).HasColumnName("SubSystemID");
        this.Property(t => t.SubSystemDesc).HasColumnName("SubSystemDesc");
        this.Property(t => t.SystemID).HasColumnName("SystemID");
        this.Property(t => t.IsActive).HasColumnName("IsActive");
        this.Property(t => t.SOrder).HasColumnName("SOrder");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Lookup_System)
            .WithMany(t => t.Lookup_SubSystem)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.SystemID);
    }
}

public List<Lookup_SubSystem> getAllSubSystems()
{
    using (DataContext)
    {
        var a = (from x in DataContext.Lookup_SubSystem
                 where x.IsActive == true
                 orderby x.SOrder ascending
                 select x);
        return a.ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable lazy-loading in your datacontext:
`((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;`
or include the navigation properties when querying the database:
`DataContext.Lookup_SubSystem.Include("Lookup_System")`

Comment: You can also the [extensions method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx): `Lookup_SubSystem.Include(s => s.Lookup_System)`

Comment: This gave a circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'OilCommander.Model.Models.Lookup_SubSystem'.

Comment: This is because Lookup_SubSystem has a reference to Lookup_System and Lookup_System has one to Lookup_SubSystem via `public virtual ICollection<Lookup_SubSystem> Lookup_SubSystem`